# How to display the whole result in the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, buffer

I used Python,for example, when I run the following code in the terminal,it can only display about 300 lines.I think whether it is relevant with the stdout buffer size.Can anyone help me solve the simple problem? Thanks.

```
for i in xrange(2000):
    print i
```

Comment: Increase the size of the scroll buffer - visible under Terminal > Preferences

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Oh,yes,it is the property of terminal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm guessing you're using command prompt in windows? 
you can go to properties -> layout -> "screen buffer size"

the default is 300. you can adjust the desired value here

Comment: Haha~,yes,your guess absolutely right.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: i'm not very certain myself! there should be some 'tick' that once you click on it, it'll become green!

Answer (score 0):

This problem could easily be solved through the use of terminal settings, however, since you did not specify what terminal emulator (eg command prompt on windows or terminal in ubuntu), I will assume that you are using a terminal only machine, for example a barebones slackware install, or ubuntu server.

in this case the best solution would be to make the script output to a log file, using code somewhat similar to this:

```
logfile = open('log.txt', 'w')
for i in xrange(2000):
    logfile.write(str(i) + "\n")
```

after execution, you would find log.txt in the same directory as the script, and be able to browse it in VIM at whatever pace you want.

please state more about your situation and setup in the future, for things involving more than the script itself, it is useful for us to know at least what OS you are running.